# Can't get size of directory in Java

Tags: java, file

I am trying get directory size but I can't get I guess because I get Always the same value   The desired result is get the size of each independent directory. How can I achieve this?

```
File file = new File(dir + "");                                                         
long totalSpace = file.getTotalSpace(); // espacio del disco en bytes
archivos.add(dir + " TS: "+totalSpace);                                                             
System.out.println(dir + " TS: "+totalSpace);
```

I get this Output:

```
C:\ TS: 550729170944
C:\$Recycle.Bin TS: 550729170944
C:\.Trash-1000 TS: 550729170944
C:\android-sdk TS: 550729170944
C:\AS2 TS: 550729170944
C:\Autodesk TS: 550729170944
C:\Boot TS: 550729170944
C:\cygwin64 TS: 550729170944
C:\ESD TS: 550729170944
C:\FacturacionElectronica TS: 550729170944
C:\Intel TS: 550729170944
C:\OneDriveTemp TS: 550729170944
C:\opt TS: 550729170944
C:\OSTotoFolder TS: 550729170944
C:\Pentaho TS: 550729170944
C:\PerfLogs TS: 550729170944
C:\production TS: 550729170944
C:\Program Files TS: 550729170944
C:\Program Files (x86) TS: 550729170944
C:\ProgramData TS: 550729170944
C:\QualityStats TS: 550729170944
C:\SQLServer2017Media TS: 550729170944
C:\SRI-DIMM TS: 550729170944
C:\temp TS: 550729170944
C:\UserGuidePDF TS: 550729170944
C:\Users TS: 550729170944
```

Comment: Just a side-note, don't practice smelling code like you have the identifier in your language. That's a bad habit and don't underestimate it even if you're just practicing something.

Comment: If a method doesn’t behave as you expect, the first thing you should do is read that method’s documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`getTotalSpace()` doesn't return the file or folder size.

> Returns the size of the partition named by this abstract pathname.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace()

Answer (score 1):

Hi mind clarifying a little bit? Do you want the size of the files (how much data is in there) or how many files are in the given directory?

This counts the number of files:

```
new File(<directory path>).listFiles().length
```

This gets the size of the directory according to this [website](https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-size)

```
private long getFolderSize(File folder) {
long length = 0;
File[] files = folder.listFiles();

int count = files.length;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (files[i].isFile()) {
        length += files[i].length();
    }
    else {
        length += getFolderSize(files[i]);
    }
}
return length;}

public void whenGetFolderSizeRecursive_thenCorrect() {
long expectedSize = 12607;

File folder = new File("src/test/resources");
long size = getFolderSize(folder);

assertEquals(expectedSize, size);}
```